# Native data compression in emacs?

Tags: compression

Is it possible to compress data (an Elisp string for example) using Emacs (without calling 3rd-party commands)? I noticed Emacs uses `zlib`, but I only found `zlib-decompress-region`.

Comment: When you say "data", do you mean data to use with Emacs? Some part of your config? A text file? A file you want to compress in Emacs and send via email? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Clarified - an data could be an elisp string, for e.g.

Comment: AFAIK automatic (de)compression is done by `jka-compr-...` and this relies on external programs for compression/decompression. A complete search of the Emacs C-sources for `compress` with [elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) only gives significant hits in [`decompress.c`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/src/decompress.c) which you already found. The other hits for `compress` are unrelated (`gnutls.c`, `image.c`, or `sound.c`).  [Github search](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/search?q=compress+extension%3Ac&unscoped_q=compress+extension%3Ac) does not work.